# Best way to rank a number in the list without sorting

Tags: mongodb, algorithm, sorting, ranking

So I am simplifying my original problem, if you'd wanna know more, view the end of the question too.

So I have a **list of numbers** with length `N`. I **can't make any changes to the original list**. I have to **find out the rank of an entry** and I'm getting `E` number of entries. What would be the best way to solve this? If I decide to use some kind of sorting algorithm, I can **never save the sorted list** created from one entry to another. I can use any kind of preprocessing and store it before any of the rank-assignment happens. My goal is to minimize time-complexity while also minimizing space-complexity.

**Original:**
I have a **mongo collection** with a thousand entries. I want to find out the **rank of a particular entry/document** on the basis of an attribute 'score'. **Without having to sort all mongo entries, what would be the best way to rank the entries**?

*PS: I am a beginner at algorithms and data structures. I posted this answer because I am unable to find a solution that applies to my specific scenario. So **apologies if I missed something that might seem very obvious**. If a mongo-specific solution already exists, that'll also work. I just need a direction on what to look for.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!*

Comment: Have you looked at [`"$rank"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/rank/) in a `"$setWindowFields"` stage?

Comment: If it's possible you can provide some same datasets